# PHP debugging on a Docker host using Vscode

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

How can I get Xdebug (or another debugger) working in VSCode for a Docker PHP container?

I found this tutorial but it is for other ides not VS code.  I haven't been able to find any other guides that come close to explaining how to do anything other than debug locally in VS Code.

https://phauer.com/2017/debug-php-docker-container-idea-phpstorm/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, since there hasn't been any answers for about a month, here is an article I found that looks like the most comprehensive answer on the web.

This link goes over the directions (way to verbose for here)
https://medium.com/@jasonterando/debugging-with-visual-studio-code-xdebug-and-docker-on-windows-b63a10b0dec

Basically:

- Install PHP Debug and PHP IntelliSense Extensions in VS code
- Add Xdebug config to your docker compose file
- Set up the Debug task
- Test the debugger